# Payment Gateway integration with Zencart

Tags: php, payment-gateway, zen-cart

I am developing a shopping cart and m using zencart for that. I use DPS payment gateway for payment handling. When user fills all the information, confirm them and process them - on successful payment it should be redirected to a partucular webpage of the site and somehow its not redirecting to that page. I am new to zencart so can anyone please help me where to configure redirect url in zencart or in DPS module.

Thank you for your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

I used to work on Zen-Cart.. I know that the redirection page is set in the Payment Gateway control panel (settings).. Not in your module config.
So, login to your DPS account and try to find your payment settings for redirection.